# Double click listener requires three taps on iOS 13

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to listen for double clicks on the full screen in iOS.

A minimal non-aframe example works when double tapping on a simple div:
https://fluoridated-nebulous-zebu.glitch.me/

But when attached to aframe's `canvas` it takes three taps on iOS to trigger:
https://classic-infrequent-pram.glitch.me/

```html
<script>
    function doubleClick(fn, timeout = 500) {
        let last = Date.now();

        return function(e) {
            const now = Date.now();
            const diff = now - last;

            console.log('single');

            if (diff < timeout) {
                fn(e);

                console.log('double');
            }

            last = now;
        }
    };

    AFRAME.registerComponent('double-click', {

        init: function() {
            this.el.sceneEl.canvas.addEventListener('click', doubleClick(this.onDoubleClick.bind(this)));
        },

        onDoubleClick: function() {
            this.el.setAttribute('color', '#ff0000');
        }
    });
</script>

<a-scene background="color: #FAFAFA">
    <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow double-click></a-box>
    <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" shadow></a-sphere>
    <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" shadow></a-cylinder>
    <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

It seems the second click is getting throttled, but I'm not sure by whom. I wasn't able to find any code that would do this in aframe's canvas setup, and even manually removing any listeners that were not my own in Safari's inspector did not make a difference.

Edit: It also works if you tap just slow enough to avoid being throttled, and just fast enough that it's under the timeout.

Edit 2: Also seems like it works on iOS 12, but not 13.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution from a Github thread: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6817#issuecomment-535919797

> came across this thread while looking into a similar issue. I found that calling preventDefault on touchstart will allow you to receive touch events as usual and thus check for double tap as before.
>
> I believe this comes down to the fact that mobile Safari changed the way it is simulating hover events (to make websites work that solely rely on hover events to open menus and such)

I'm now listening for `touchstart` instead, and calling `e.preventDefault()` on the  first event:

```js
function doubleClick (fn, timeout = 500) {
  let last = Date.now();

  return function (e) {
    const now = Date.now();
    const diff = now - last;

    console.log('single');

    if (diff < timeout) {
      fn(e);

      console.log('double');
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    last = now;
  }
};

AFRAME.registerComponent('double-click', {

  init: function () {
    this.el.sceneEl.canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', doubleClick(this.onDoubleClick.bind(this)));
  },
        
  onDoubleClick: function () {
    this.el.setAttribute('color', '#ff0000');
  }
});
```

Of course, preventing default might cause issues in your situation, so YMMV. Also still should handle click as fallback for normally working devices.